# ExpressionEngine 2.1 re-install admin login failure

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I replaced a working ExpressionEngine 2.1 install with a reworked one that replaced all templates and so on.  I made a backup of the WORKING database and WORKING DIRECTORY.  I failed to remember to clear the cache beforehand.

I've tried to reinstall the original WORKING EE on a new dev server to be able to compare some pages and so on.  I have run the ee_wizard and the environment is good.  I can almost get the site up, but it has some references to the production domain i can't track down.  The biggest problem is the admin cp login.  I put in the correct login, but the page only refreshes (clears the name and password fields).  If i put in an incorrect login, i get an error.

I've tried
-- delete from exp_sessions;
-- delete from exp_security_hashes;
-- incognito window 
-- modifying expressionengine/config/config.php values for cookie prefix, domain

anything else i can try?

I really need to get in to check some things

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dumping/searching the DB for references to the old domain and doing a find/replace?  Also I would do a grep of the config files, htaccess, etc... for instances of the old domain name and change them.

Comment: Good idea and using grep found a bunch in the db dump file.  Edited those out and dropped db, used sanitized dump file to restore.  Found no instances in directories for EE. Problem still exists

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your apache or mysql logs?

Comment: No errors in apache or mysql. However, the select it is trying to pull off is WHERE `g`.`site_id` = '1' AND `member_id` = 0 AND m.group_id = g.group_id;
the member id for admin is 1..so i can see that's an issue.

Comment: Yeah...I would just change that 1 to a 0 in the db and see if that allows you in. It seems like maybe that got altered somewhere along the line...I have had that problem before with db dumps in mysql and reimports... "Certain database dump programs, such as older versions of phpMyAdmin, do not respect MySQL's SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; directive. The result of this is when importing a faulty database dump, your anonymous user record gets imported as (highest user ID) +1 instead of user ID 0."